# package-installed-p vs fboundp

Tags: package, conditionals

What should I use:

```
(when (package-installed-p 'ivy)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-x b") #'ivy-switch-buffer))
```

or:

```
(when (fboundp 'ivy-switch-buffer)
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-x b") #'ivy-switch-buffer))
```

or:

```
(eval-after-load ivy ...)  ; haven't tested it yet
```

I try to rebind key based on a package presence. We are in 2021 so it is safe to assume of presence of `package.el` but what if I installed a package from git/hg?

**UPDATE** With `fboundp` & compilation of `.emacs` it doesn't redefine key.

Works with `package-installed-p` though... I haven't `(ivy-mode +1)` so function definition `ivy-switch-buffer` can be in form of `autoload`...

Comment: The question is likely to invite opinion-based answers...

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: If you want to actually make sure the library is loaded then use `require`. You can do that without raising an error if not found by doing `(require 'the-library nil t)`. See `C-h f require`.

Comment: `require` adds delay to boot time. Packages register autoloads to avoid eager loading... I was searching for the way to discover such "registration". `package-installed-p` & `eval-after-load` are nice alternatives. **update** it is for `.emacs`. For libraries only the `require` is viable option...

Comment: A soft `require` (e.g. `(require 'foo nil t)`) doesn't add delay, if the library has already been loaded. It just checks `load-history`. It takes time only if the library has not yet been loaded, by loading the library. It all depends on what behavior you want. As I said, *if you want to actually make sure the library is loaded* when the sexp is evaluated then use a soft require. (If you want to load the library, and bind the key, at some later time, that's a different story.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `eval-after-load` - the function will not be defined if the package is not loaded, so checking whether it's installed does not help and checking whether the function is defined (the `fboundp` stuff) will not load it.

BTW, `ivy` should be quoted in the `eval-after-load` call:

```el
(eval-after-load 'ivy
    (global-set-key (kbd "C-x b") #'ivy-switch-buffer))
```

That's assuming that the function `ivy-switch-buffer` is defined in a file that provides the symbol `ivy` when loaded. That's usually the last thing done when loading a file: if you check `ivy.el` there should be a `(provide 'ivy)` at the bottom.

Alternatively, you can use a file name (in various forms) as argument:

```el
(eval-after-load "ivy" ...)
```

Do `C-h f eval-after-load RET` and read the doc string for all the gory details.

EDIT: as the OP points out in a comment, `package-installed-p` works *if you call it after calling `package-intiialize`*: `package-initialize` loads the files in `package-load-list`so afterwards, checking whether the package is installed (i.e. it was in `package-load-list`) or whether it is loaded do the same thing. I still prefer `eval-after-load` because it will DTRT without extra conditions, but to each his/her own.

Comment: Seems that `(package-installed-p 'ivy)` works even if I haven't loaded module. To trigger `eval-after-load` I need to `(ignore-errors (require ...))`. I think `eval-after-load` vs `package-installed-p` are rivals and `eval-after-load` wins when package installed from Git, and `package-installed-p` wins after `(package-initialize)`. Tnx!

Comment: `(package-initialize)` loads all the packages in `package-load-list`, so as long as you check afterwards, it should indeed work.